# Errors building tesseract Android tools

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to build Tesseract for android and have been getting issues. I am following a [tutorial](http://www.codepool.biz/ocr/making-an-android-ocr-application-with-tesseract.html) where the following instructions have been given to build Tesseract.

```
cd <project-directory>
curl -O https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
curl -O http://leptonica.googlecode.com/files/leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
tar -zxvf tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
tar -zxvf leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
rm -f tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
rm -f leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
mv tesseract-3.02.02 jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
mv leptonica-1.69 jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
ndk-build -j8
android update project --target 1 --path .
ant debug (release)
```

Firstly there is no path at (i.e no `src` directory)

```
jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
```

So I am not too sure where they should go, so I left them in their extracted folder.
Also when running

```
ndk-build -j8
```

I get the following errors

```
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/pixa.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
#include <allheaders.h>
                       ^
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/pix.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
#include <allheaders.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/readfile.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
#include <allheaders.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/jni.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
#include <allheaders.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/utilities.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error:   allheaders.h: No such file or directory
#include <allheaders.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/writefile.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
#include <allheaders.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/box.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
#include <allheaders.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/pix.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/readfile.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/utilities.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/jni.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/writefile.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/pixa.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/box.o] Error 1
```

UPDATE:

Interestingly after starting again

```
mv tesseract-ocr jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
mv leptonica-1.69 jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
```

are working.

During building I get the following errors:

```
jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/dict/permdawg.cpp: In member function 'void tesseract::Dict::go_deeper_dawg_fxn(const char*, const BLOB_CHOICE_LIST_VECTOR&, int, const CHAR_FRAGMENT_INFO*, bool, WERD_CHOICE*, float*, float*, WERD_CHOICE*, int*, void*)':
jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/dict/permdawg.cpp:208:62: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
       fprintf(output_ambig_words_file_, word_str.string());
                                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/tess/src/dict/permdawg.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Someone please help me, been at it for a while

Comment: if `jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src` is empty, that means at least this step: `mv tesseract-3.02.02 jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src` failed. What error messages did you get when you ran all the commands from the tutorial ?

Comment: I didn't run all the commands. I stopped when I got to `ndk-build -j8` because I was getting the above stated errors (lower part of original post).

Comment: If your src directories aren't there, that means that the steps that are actually failing are before `ndk-build`.

Comment: how can I solve this?

Comment: Remove everything and start again from scratch. You should get error an error message when a command fails, then stop and share it.

Comment: I just updated the post with the new error message

Comment: thanks. To fix this error, pass `-Wno-error=format-security` to the compiler. You can do so by adding `APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security` to the file *jni/Application.mk*

Comment: I am still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.
These are the steps I followed:

- Downloaded the tesseract_android_tools project from github.com/alanv/tesseract-android-tools
- Extracted it and moved to tesseract-android-tools via Terminal
- curl -O https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
- curl -O http://leptonica.googlecode.com/files/leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
- tar -zxvf tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
- tar -zxvf leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
- rm -f tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
- rm -f leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
- mv tesseract-3.02.02 jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
- mv leptonica-1.69 jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
- I tried running `android-ndk-r9` but it kept on throwing the error `jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/dict/permdawg.cpp:208:62:      error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  cc1plus.exe: some warnings being treated as errors`
- I modified jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/dict/permdawg.cpp line 208 from `fprintf(output_ambig_words_file_, word_str.string());` to `fprintf(output_ambig_words_file_, "%s", word_str.string());`
- I tried running `android.bat update project -p .` but kept on complaining that `Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid. 
  Please provide a --target to the 'android.bat update' command.`
- I provided the target by first running `android list targets` to get the targets I have and then `android update project -t 7 -p .` since 7 was my preferred target
- That worked.
- Sorry for the late reply